# R - Discrepancy in summary(data) and summary(data$variable)

Tags: r, summary

I have a [data set](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hfconamore/RepData_PeerAssessment1/hfconamore-patch-1/testdata.csv) with 61 observations and 2 variables. When I summary the whole data, the quantiles, median, mean and max of the second variable are sometimes different from the result I get from summary the second variable alone. Why is that?

```
data <- read.csv("testdata.csv")

head(data)
#   Group.1     x
# 1 10/1/12     0
# 2 10/2/12   126
# 3 10/3/12 11352
# 4 10/4/12 12116
# 5 10/5/12 13294
# 6 10/6/12 15420

summary(data)
#   Group.1           x        
# 10/1/12 : 1   Min.   :    0  
# 10/10/12: 1   1st Qu.: 6778  
# 10/11/12: 1   Median :10395  
# 10/12/12: 1   Mean   : 9354  
# 10/13/12: 1   3rd Qu.:12811  
# 10/14/12: 1   Max.   :21194  
# (Other) :55             

summary(data[2])
#       x        
# Min.   :    0  
# 1st Qu.: 6778  
# Median :10395  
# Mean   : 9354  
# 3rd Qu.:12811  
# Max.   :21194  

# The following code yield different result:

summary(data$x)
# Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# 0    6778   10400    9354   12810   21190
```

Comment: Your calls are equivalent (after S3 resolution) to `summary.data.frame(data[2])` and `summary.default(data$x)`. The functions are defined slightly differently, and it appears that the statistics are a little different, too. Calculating the quartiles is "up to interpretation" depending on the length of the numeric vectors, and not all functions in R make the same assumptions as each other or you. Either find the method you prefer or calculate them yourself (after reading `?quantile` for some details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@r2evans' comment is correct in that the discrepancy is caused by differences in `summary.data.frame` and `summary.default`.

The default value of `digits` for both methods is `max(3L, getOption("digits") - 3L)`. If you haven't changed your options, this will evaluate to `4L`. However, the two methods use their `digits` argument differently when formatting the output, which is the reason for the differences in the two methods' output. From `?summary`:

> `digits`: integer, used for number formatting with `signif()` (for `summary.default`) or `format()` (for `summary.data.frame`).

Say we have the vector of `x`´s  summary statistics in the question:

```
q <- append(quantile(data$x), mean(data$x), after = 3L)
q
##   0%      25%      50%               75%     100% 
## 0.00  6778.00 10395.00  9354.23 12811.00 21194.00
```

In `summary.default` the output is formatted by using `signif`, which rounds it's input to the supplied number of significant `digits`:

```
signif(q, digits = 4L)
## 0%   25%   50%         75%  100% 
##  0  6778 10400  9354 12810 21190
```

While `summary.data.frame` uses `format`, which uses it's `digits` argument as only a *sugggestion* ([`?format`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/format.html)) for the number of significant digits to display:

```
format(q, digits = 4L)
##      0%     25%     50%             75%    100% 
## "    0" " 6778" "10395" " 9354" "12811" "21194"
```

Thus, when using the default `digits` argument value `4`, `summary.default(data$x)` rounds the 5-digit quantiles to only 4 significant digits; but `summary.data.frame(data[2])` displays the 5-digit quantiles witout rounding.

If you explicitly supply the `digits` argument as larger than 4, you'll get identical results:

```
summary(data[2], digits = 5L)
##        x          
## Min.   :    0.0  
## 1st Qu.: 6778.0  
## Median :10395.0  
## Mean   : 9354.2  
## 3rd Qu.:12811.0  
## Max.   :21194.0  

summary(data$x, digits = 5L)
##   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##    0.0  6778.0 10395.0  9354.2 12811.0 21194.0
```

As an extreme example of the differences of the two methods with the default `digits`:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1e5 + 0:100)

summary(df$a)
##    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
##  100000  100000  100000  100000  100100  100100 

summary(df)
##       a         
## Min.   :100000  
## 1st Qu.:100025  
## Median :100050  
## Mean   :100050  
## 3rd Qu.:100075  
## Max.   :100100
```